# How to prove this locus?

Tags: geometry

What is the locus of the midpoint of a line segment that is drawn from a given external point $P$ to a given circle with center $O$ and radius $r$ ?

Playing along with Geogebra I've noticed that the locus of these point is a circle with diameter $r$ but i dont know how to prove it .Can you please give me some hints (not solutions)?

(Only geometric methods,i.e no analitycal methods allowed)
Thanks.

EDIT:
@Jhon Douma [image]

Comment: Is the point moving?

Comment: This is trivial using analytic geometry. Are you allowed to use it ?

Comment: @Lucian Unfortunately i am not allowed to use it.

Comment: @John Douma the point is fixed.

Comment: @Nameless I am not clear on what you are asking. If $P$ is fixed and the circle is fixed, then just bisect the line segment $PO$ to get the midpoint. Is that your question?

Comment: @John Douma i am asking suggestions to prove that all the midpoints of these line segments lie on a circle ,not how to get these midpoints.

Comment: @Nameless They don't lie on a circle. They consist of the set of points in the plane whose distance from $O$ is greater than $\frac{r}{2}$.

Comment: @Jhon Douma See Edit.

Comment: This "midpoint" construction amounts to a _similarity_, scaling the plane about $P$ by a factor of $1/2$. _Every_ set of points in the plane gets "reduced in size while keeping its shape the same", not just a circle. (Nor does it matter that $P$ is external to the original circle.)

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang That is awesome. The simplest solutions are the best.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let the centre of the circle be $O$ and the external point be $P$. Let $Q$ be a point on the circle. Let the midpoint of $\overline{PQ}$ be $R$.

Through $R$, draw a line parallel to $\overline{OQ}$ and let it meet $PO$ at $S$. What is the distance $\overline{RS}$?

Comment: The simplicity of your solution leave me amazed.Thank you

Comment: @Nameless I am but a somewhat advanced beginner in these things. You should see Blue's proofs. Youll be more than amazed.

Answer (score 4):

Let O be the centre of the circle and P the external point. Let points A and B be on the circle so that AB is a diameter and BOAP is a straight line. Let the midpoint of BP be B' and the midpoint of AP be A'.

Now consider any point C on the circle and let C' be the midpoint of CP. Then it it straightforward to show that triangle BCP is similar to triangle B'C'P and that triangle ACP is similar to triangle A'C'P. Both pairs are in ratio 2:1.

Now angle BCA is 90 therefore so is angle B'C'A'. Therefore C' lies on a circle whose diameter is A'B', with the required diameter equal to one half of AB

Answer (score 2):

HINT...start by parametrizing the point On the circle with $$(x,y)=(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta)$$ then write down the midpoint in terms of $\theta$ which you can then eliminate...

Comment: I should have worded it differently...  when i said that the problem should be solved only by geometric methods i was trying to say that i am not allowed to use analytical ones.Sorry for my unclearness.

Answer (score 2):

You can assume the Cartesian co-ords for your point P (a, b) and centre of the circle O (h, k) . Then, you'll be able to derive an equation for the circle (easily). Then, take a certain point (x<sub>1</sub>,  y<sub>1</sub>) on the circle and it'll be really easy to derive the co-ords for the midpoint joining those two. Then apply the property that (x<sub>1</sub>,  y<sub>1</sub>) is on the circle. I think that'd be able to do it.

Comment: how would i go without analitycal methods ?

Comment: I think G-Man has given a quite a decent solution if you only care about geometric methods.